# Expand height of relative positioned parent div to the height of an absolute positioned child div

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have seen many questions on SO that are similar to this one but i haven't found a solution that fits for my situation. 
What i have tried from the solutions i read is to set the height or minimum height of the left column to be equal to the height of the image or right column 
 via JS / Jquery but somehow it didn't work, i don't know why.

I have a relative positioned parent div which has two child divs (Columns). The first child div (left) is relative positioned and the second child div (right) is absolute positioned. The left child div has some text while the right child div has an image. The parent div's height goes as far as the left child div's height and it doesn't show most part of an image that's in the right child div.

How can i make the parent div expand to the height that's equal to the image inside the right child div.

The layout is extremely important so i can't change it. Both Css and JS / jQuery is welcomed.

HTML

```
<div class="parent" id="parent">
  <div class="leftcolumn">This is the left Column</div>
  <div class="rightcolumn"><img src="somelinkhere"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.leftcolumn
{
   width: 25%;
   position: relative;
}

.rightcolumn
{
   width: 75%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Can u send Jsfiddle exemple ? thx

Comment: Unless you know the image height and therefor the target height for the parent, this is impossible using CSS alone, because absolute positioning has taken the element out of the normal flow, so it has no influence whatsoever any more over its parent's dimensions. As for a JS/jQuery solution - please try something yourself first. Happy to discusss/help with certain details, but StackOverflow is not a code order service.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but, why? I see no reason whatsoever for the right column to need to be positioned absolutely.

Comment: The layout is need to create a layout where we have text on the left, image on the right for the first row then image on the left and text on the right for the second row. That mean's the design is truly left text, right image and this helps when the website gets to tablets and mobile. Otherwise on phones/tablets, it would be a horizontal stack of first left text, first right image, second left image and second left text which isn't right. We wanted it to be image, text, image, text, etc...

Comment: You still don't need to use absolute positioning for that. Use a grid system, use inline blocks, even float and clearfix is better than this - there are many other, more flexible ways than absolute positioning.

Comment: Exactly. Float the first circle to the right, the second one to the left, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are actually trying to achieve, using absolute positioning is probably the least flexible ways.

If you are using a grid system I suggest you use it, but below is a HTML & CSS only "quickfix" using floats.

```css
img {
  width: 25%;
  /* for testing so we can see where image would be */
  height: 50px; background: #ccc;
}

.textcolumn {
  width: 75%;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* clearfix to make each container fully contain its floated elements */
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* alternate the display between odd & even containers */
.container:nth-child(odd) img{  float: right; }
.container:nth-child(odd) .textcolumn {  float: left;}
.container:nth-child(even) img{  float: left;}
.container:nth-child(even) .textcolumn{  float: right; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="textcolumn">This is the text block that will float to the left </div>
  <img src="somelinkhere">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="textcolumn">This is the text block that will float to the right</div>
  <img src="somelinkhere">
</div>
```